# How to update DB table from gcm server response

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, push

My app is sending push successfully. Below is the details. I am maintaining one DB table for device token id and status field. 
Now looking for failure id to set the status 0 in table. So next time I can fetch only status 1 ID only.

Please help me how to read the below message for above purpose.

```
{
  "multicast_id": 9000754561212282225,
  "success": 625,
  "failure": 375,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    },
    {
      "message_id": "0:1463996561713000%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
      "message_id": "0:1463996561711827%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
      "message_id": "0:1463996561712955%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
      "message_id": "0:1463996561713911%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    },
........
    {
      "message_id": "0:1463996561713114%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd"
    },  
   {
      "message_id": "0:1463996561889865%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) results are:

> Array of objects representing the status of the messages processed.
>   The objects are listed in the same order as the request (i.e., for
>   each registration ID in the request, its result is listed in the same
>   index in the response).

So each item that is not a message_id represents a failed message and thus the corresponding token should not be used, marked as 0 in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is their any way to read the below return string "message_id": "0:1463996561713114%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd". I mean is there any relation between return string and Registration ID?

Comment: Yes there is a relationship. When you use registration_ids the responses are in the same order as submitted. So if "message_id": "0:1463996561713114%2b8e613cf9fd7ecd" is the 3rd item in the response it is corresponding to the 3rd registration id in the request.